# Как с помощью cmake скомпилить одновременно и статическую и динамическую библиотеку?

Tags: c, cmake, библиотеки, сборка

Есть такой cmake, что в него нужно добавить, чтоб компилилась не только статическая, но и динамическая библиотека?(именно обе сразу, а не по отдельности)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.2)
project(libtfidfmetric C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(inc)
file(GLOB C_SOURCES "src/*.c")
add_library(libtfidfmetric STATIC ${C_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(libtfidfmetric m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam

```
add_library(MyLib SHARED source1.c source2.c)
add_library(MyLibStatic STATIC source1.c source2.c)
```

но как пишут, на Windows нужно будет пошаманить с именами (в случае винды статическая и динамическая библиотека не различается в имени) или в разные папки попробовать сложить.

Comment: «*в случае винды статическая и динамическая библиотека не различается в имени*» — различаются, просто к динамической идёт довеском ещё и статическая с импортируемыми символами и с тем же именем...

Comment: А на linux тоже нельзя с одним именем создать? Я пытался создать с одним именем, но разным расширением, но не получилось

Comment: @DenverToha, имена целей должны быть разные, а имя файла можно поменять как-то так: `set_target_properties(MyLibStatic PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME MyLib)`